# Cordova/Ionic on Android - How to force index.html to pull latest src from my.com/app.com

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, web-applications, ionic-framework

I have a dynamic app that loads most of the js/html/css from my server.

However, on Android, with Ionic/Cordova, when changing my.com/app.js which is pulled in index.html,

it seems index.html itself doesn’t bother re-loading the index.html every time (even after app restart)

How can I force index.html or otherwise get Ionic/AngularJS/JS to use latest from my.com/my.js — eg, controller.js?

Comment: uninstall app and reinstall from device so that you can clear cache memory and your app can reload all js css

Comment: see link [here](http://blog.httpwatch.com/2007/12/10/two-simple-rules-for-http-caching/) for HTML caching.

Comment: raj, frank.. my intention is that the USER get's a new version of the app (ie, new js/css/html). I'm loading most of this from the server.

Comment: @mylord You can manually remove the cached page, by going to the Apps setting and emptying the cache. Programatically see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers/2068407#2068407) over here